# Elastic Search 5.1 - java api for random score

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic search 5.1.2

I made randome score java api query on version 2.2, but not suitable for version 5.1. Here is my code (works on version 2.2).

```
FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionQuery = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery( boolQuery);
functionQuery
        .add( ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction( 1)) // error from 'add'
        .boostMode( "replace");
```

How can I convert it as 5.1 version code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work in 5.1.2:

```
final BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
final FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScoreQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders
                .functionScoreQuery(boolQuery, ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction(1))
                .boostMode(CombineFunction.REPLACE);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as I expect. Is there any reference about this with ES 5.x?

Comment: @J.Done, i didn't look for it, to be honest, potentialy, it should be something

Comment: @Mysterion i went through your answer and i am able to convert partially but any idea on how to add functions and filter ? for a query like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953306/how-to-covert-this-elastic-search-functional-score-query-to-java-api